# Spark - How to encrypt the files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a spark program to encrypt the files.

**Current Approach:**

- Write files (orc, csv) to temporary location
- Read the files and encrypt file to different location.

However, the problem with current approach is, files are stored without encryption temporarily. Is there a way I can read the table using spark and directly write encrypted files. without using temporary location.

Comment: Typically this kind of security is achieved at file system level, using transparent data encryption for example https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html

Comment: @mazaneicha I am aware of that and that is in place. However we have to do this before sending files outside network.